# Undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysql-connect, undefined-function

I have ran `aptitude install php5-mysql` (and restarted MySQL/Apache 2), but I am still getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/validate.php on line 21

`phpinfo()` says the /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini file has been parsed.

Comment: How about other built in PHP/MySql functions? Do they work?

Comment: Perhaps not, as I have tried entering incorrect user/pass and my 'or die' statement is not showing!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Well, this is your chance! It looks like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is ready; use that instead.

Try checking to see if the PHP MySQL extension module is being loaded:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If it's not there, add the following to the `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Comment: Is this a better way to connect to a database? I will look into it but I would really like to get this working first as it worked previously until I moved to a new server.

Comment: It is. `mysql_*` functions are dangerous and deprecated as of PHP 4.1. Check your Apache error logs and restart the server. Does that work?

Comment: I'm using xampp, after adding that line to php.ini I get the following message in apache error.log _Unable to load dynamic library '\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_mysql.dll_

Comment: @defmx Does the .dll file exist at that path? If not you need to install it.

Comment: omg, I would have NEVER figured this out. This line existed in my `php.ini` file but was commented out. Shouldn't the installer for `php_mysql` uncomment this line for you?

Answer (score 110):

In case, you are using PHP7 already, the formerly deprecated functions `mysql_*` were removed entirely, so you should update your code using the PDO-functions or `mysqli_*` functions instead.

If that's not possible, as a **workaround**, I created a small PHP include file, that recreates the old `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*()`-functions: [fix_mysql.inc.php](https://github.com/rubo77/php-mysql-fix)

Comment: Perfect solution for my case, I could not just upgrade yet and break all my existing code. However, the global $con variable in your file was a problem because the included file was not able to read the global variable of the parent class in which constructor I included it. However, I simply created a connection variable inside the functions of the included file where needed. Now my code works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks .. it saved my life where production was upgraded to php7 and php5 application broke down

Comment: This was my problem today when godaddy moved my server.  Despite selecting php 5.6 (not 7.0+) and enabling mysql and mysqli options in cpanel, 'mysql_connect' was still undefined.
It was still 2 hours of work to diagnose and fix, but your script saved me from making it 8-10 hours!  Thank you.

Answer (score 62):

I see that you tagged this with Ubuntu. Most likely the MySQL driver (and possibly MySQL) is not installed. Assuming you have [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) or terminal access and sudo permissions, log into the server and run this:

```sh
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
```

If the MySQL packages or the php5-mysql package are already installed, this will update them.

---

**UPDATE**

Since this answer still gets the occasional click I am going to update it to include **PHP 7**. PHP 7 requires a different package for MySQL so you will want to use a different argument for the apt-get command.

```sh
# Replace 7.4 with your version of PHP
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common php7.4 php7.4-mysql
```

And importantly, `mysql_connect()` has been deprecated since PHP v5.5.0. Refer the official documentation here: [PHP: mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: I get Unable to locate package php7.0

Comment: Replace 7.0 with 7.3

Comment: for me it was : sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql && sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 59):

If someone came here with the problem of [docker php official images](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), type below command inside the docker container.

```
$ docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
```

For more information, please refer to the link above `How to install more PHP extensions` section(But it's a bit difficult for me...).

Or this doc may help you.

> https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/

Comment: `mysql` is what I want

Answer (score 20):

I was also stuck with the same problem of undefined MySQL_connect().I tried to make changes in PHP.ini file but it was giving me the same error.
Then I came to this solution where I changed my code from  depreciated php functions to new functions.

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);

mysqli_select_db($con,dbname); 
//To select the database

session_start(); //To start the session

$query=mysqli_query($con,your query); 
//made query after establishing connection with database.
```

I hope this will help you .
This solution is correctly working for me .

EDIT:

If you upgrade form old php you need to `apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Run the page and search for `mysql`. If not found, run the following in the shell and restart the Apache server:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
```

Also make sure you have all the following lines uncommented somewhere in your apache2.conf (or in your conf.d/php.ini) file, from

```
;extension=php_mysql.so
```

to

```
extension=php_mysql.so
```

Answer (score 8):

In php.ini file

change this

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
```

into

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess is your PHP installation wasn't compiled with MySQL support.

Check your configure command (`php -i | grep mysql`). You should see something like `'--with-mysql=shared,/usr'`.

You can check for complete instructions at http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php. Although, I would rather go with the solution proposed by @wanovak.

Still, I think you need MySQL support in order to use PDO.

Answer (score 3):

The question is tagged with `ubuntu`, but the solution of un-commenting the `extension=mysqli.dll` is specific to windows. I am confused here?!, anyways, first thing run `<? php phpinfo ?>` and search for `mysql*` under `Configuration` heading. If you don't see such a thing implies you have not installed or enabled `php-mysql`. So first install `php-mysql`

`sudo apt get install php-mysql`

This command will install `php-mysql` depending on the `php` you have already installed, so no worries about the version!!.

Then comes the unix specific solution, in the `php.ini` file un-comment the line

```
extension=msql.so
```

verify that `msql.so` is present in `/usr/lib/php/<timestamp_folder>`,
**ELSE**

```
extension=path/to/msql.so
```

Then finally restart the `apache` and `mysql` services, and you should now see the `mysql` section under `Configrations` heading in `phpinfo page`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because the project I was working on was developed on php 5.6 and after install, the project was unable to run on php7.1.

Just for anyone that uses Vagrant with ubuntu/nginx, in the nginx directory(/etc/nginx/), there is a directory named "sites-available" which contains a file named like the url configured for the vagrant maschine. In my case was homestead.app. Within this file there is a line that says something like

```
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
```

There you can change the php version to the desired for that particular site.

Googled this but wasnt really able to find a simple answer that said where to look and what to change.

Hope that this helps anyone.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting the error as

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Kindly login to the cPanel **>>** Click on Select Php version **>>** select the extension MYSQL

Comment: There is no suggestion in the question that the OP is using CPanel.

Answer (score -1):

For CentOS 7.8 & PHP 7.3

```
yum install rh-php73-php-mysqlnd
```

And then restart apache/php.

Comment: Please share more details. Are you sure this adds `mysql_connect()` to PHP?

Answer (score -3):

(Windows mysql config)

Step 1 : Go To Apache Control Panel > Apache > Config > PHP.ini

Step 2 : Search in Notepad (Ctrl+F) For: `;extension_dir = ""` (could be commented with a `;`). Replace this line with: `extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"` (please do not you need to remove the `;` on the beginning of the sentence).

Step 3 : Search For: `extension=php_mysql.dll` and remove the `;` in the beginning.

Step 4 : Save and Restart You Apache HTTP Server. (On Windows this usually done via a UI)

That's it :)

If you get errors about missing `php_mysql.dll` you'll probably need to download this file from either the php.net site or the pecl.php.net. (Please be causius about where you get it from)

More info on [PHP: Installation of extensions on Windows - Manual](http://php.net/manual/it/install.windows.extensions.php)

Comment: While this might be correct for Windows, this question is tagged Ubuntu, which most certainly doesn't have `C:\\php` on the system.

Comment: @tadman doesn't matter if that's for Ubuntu, it has worked for me today after a fresh installation on windows.

Comment: @RaviGauravPandey The original question pertained to Ubuntu. That it works for you on Windows isn't the point. This is a Windows answer to an Ubuntu question.

Answer (score -4):

There must be some syntax error. Copy/paste this code and see if it works:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    ?
```

I had the same error message. It turns out I was using the `msql_connect()` function instead of `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: OP has undefined function mysql_connect and not msql_connect so he didn't type it incorrectly as you suggest.