# How to get osCommerce 2.2 running on PHP 5.4?

Tags: oscommerce, php-5.4

I recently upgraded PHP to 5.4 and after adding some tweaks now the old osCommerce installation of a customer with lots of customisations is running again, but there is still a problem:

**if you put an item in your cart the cart stays empty**

How can I fix this?
Is there a certain php value I can set in php.ini so the session is working properly?

---

### What I have tweaked so far:

**Problem:** all prices are 0 and there is no currency
**Solution:** adding `!isset($currency) ||` in the paragraph `//
(see [$currency not set in application_top under PHP 5.4](http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/392694-currency-not-set-in-application-top-under-php-54/)  )

**Problem:** register_globals is REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0
**Solution:** I simulated `register_globals` with this: https://serverfault.com/a/547285/128892

**and I added this to `includes/application_top.php`:**

```
// Bugfix PHP 5.4:
$HTTP_USER_AGENT=$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];
$HTTP_HOST=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$SERVER_NAME=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$PHP_SELF=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$HTTP_GET_VARS=$_GET;
$HTTP_POST_VARS=$_POST;
register_globals();
```

comment out this line:

```
#ini_get('register_globals') or exit('FATAL ERROR: register_globals is disabled in php.ini, please enable it!');
```

also I had to correct some removed functions in `includes/functions/sessions.php`: `session_unregister()` and `session_is_registered()`

---

Problem remaining:
Items filled into the cart don't get added to the cart. seems like the session isn't known in the add_cart page.

Comment: I cound not fix this last problem, so after trying diffenent attempts I decided to take the effort and convert the shop with all its customisations into oscommerce 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cound not fix this last problem, so after trying diffenent attempts I decided to take the effort and convert the shop with all its customisations into oscommerce 2.3 which still runs on PHP 5.4 (up to PHP 5.6).

*Note that later, to get oscommerce running on php7 you'll need another fix for mysql functions to fix problems like [Undefined function mysql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37877644/1069083)*

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Found by comparing my 2.2ms2 code with rc2a version.

In application_top change

```
$cart->add_cart($_POST['products_id'], $cart->get_quantity(tep_get_uprid($_POST['products_id'], $_POST['id']))+$quantity, $_POST['id']);
```

to

```
$cart->add_cart($_POST['products_id'], $cart->get_quantity(tep_get_uprid($_POST['products_id'], $_POST['id']))+$_POST['quantity'], $_POST['id']);
```