# Wordpress Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /wp-includes/wp-db.php:1570

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, fatal-error

I am in big trouble. I installed a nulled version of woocommerce cart based shipping plugin and i found it not relevant according to my requiremnet and deleted that plugin from plugins area. After deleting that plugin my site went down. Its continuously showing me Fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/dev/public_html/new/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1570
Stack trace:
#0 /home/dev/public_html/new/wp-includes/wp-db.php(658): wpdb->db_connect()
#1 /home/dev/public_html/new/wp-includes/load.php(404): wpdb->__construct('dev_test', 'password', 'dev_test_ne...', 'localhost')
#2 /home/dev/public_html/new/wp-settings.php(107): require_wp_db()
#3 /home/dev/public_html/new/wp-config.php(82): require_once('/home/dev/p...')
#4 /home/dev/public_html/new/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/dev/p...')
#5 /home/dev/public_html/new/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/dev/p...')
#6 /home/dev/public_html/new/index.php(17): require('/home/dev/p...')
#7 {main} thrown in /home/dev/public_html/new/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1570
```

I tried replacing all core files excluding wp-config.php and wp-content folder. Still I am getting the same error.

Also, i tried renameing plugins folder but the error is there.

Can you guys suggest me how i can get my site back.

Comment: where is the website hosted ? If you are using web hosting service you could restore a backup and go from there.

Comment: are you deleted before deactivated the plugin ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined function mysql\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825108/undefined-function-mysql-connect)

Comment: @user2584538 i deactivated plugin from the plugins area in admin panel and deleted it. That's it.

Comment: Can you reinstall the plugin and see if that restores fuctionality?

Comment: I tried to put the plugin files in plugins folder but i am not able to activate it because i cant access site admin as well

Comment: Of course you need mysql_connect to login. Can you access the database directly?

Comment: Sorry, but I have realized that restoring the plugin cannot possible fix this problem as the database connection is made before the plugins are loaded. WordPress needs to read the database to determine the active plugins. So, this error will occur before the plugin has a chance to load. I am stupid!

Answer (score 27):

I encountered this problem upgrading from PHP 5 to PHP 7 (on Windows). The problem was `mysqli` PHP extension was not enabled. If mysqli is not available Wordpress 5+ detects this and will instead attempt to connect to the database with deprecated `mysql_connect()` calls. This leads to a very misleading error message about mysql_connect() function not being available (*since we don't want this function*).

In **php.ini** make sure `extension_dir` is set (use full directory name) and mysqli extension is enabled

```
extension_dir = "C:\php-7.3.10\ext"
...
extension=mysqli
```

To double check what extensions are active you can run the following code

```
<pre>
<?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: When using IIS you must restart the site or the app pool otherwise the setting will not take effect

Comment: In Windows 10 Professional, in IIS in the Connections pane, I had to right-click the computer name (topmost item) and select Stop, then do it again for Start. Just restarting the site did not cause the php.ini changes to be taking into effect.

Answer (score 8):

Possible error sources:

- Since PHP 7, `mysql_*` functions have been removed, see [PHP's official overview of the MySQL drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php).
- You use PHP 5.x and have not enabled the `mysql` extension, but `mysqli` and/or `pdo_mysql` instead.

You can set

```
define('WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', true);
```

in your `wp-config.php` file to make WordPress use the mysqli extension.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for all plugins. I had a problem with a WP blog after I migrated it to a server with PHP 7.3. And I isolated the problem due to a plugin folder named 'cystats'. However this define doesn't make it work. I had to remove the plugin at the end.

Answer (score 6):

It happens for me when I switch from 5.6 php to 7.0.

Just enable "mysqli" in your select php version if you use cPanel.

Comment: This is what solved the issue for me. Quite straightforward and easy suggestion. It was enabled by default in direct admin php selector but for some reason for this 1 site it wasn't. Enabling it solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just registered to give a big thank you for the solution of enabling mysqli. I have been struggling to get WordPress running on a Synology for the past 3.5 hours and this finally fixed my dreaded "The site is experiencing technical difficulties."

For any other Synology users ending up in this topic after trying to find a solution, to fix this on Synology, you need to...

- Go to Web Station
- Select PHP Settings
- Double-click the PHP profile you are using (or click once and choose [Edit])
- Select General Settings and scroll to the extensions list
- Find mysqli and enable by placing a checkmark
- Push the [OK] button (no restart required)

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question on this page. Perhaps you should leave a comment on the answer that suggested enabling mysqli and upvote their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your wp-config.php file for the following line:

```
define('WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', true);
```

If you find it, delete the line. Your problem should be fixed.

If not, you can tick `nd_mysqli` extension in the PHP 7 configuration, and disable the `mysqli` extension on Cpanel -> Select PHP version.

Source:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/database-cache-causing-503-errors-when-upgrading-to-php-7/

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error seems be simple, `mysql_*` functions are not enabled.
Check with `phpinfo()` if these functions are truly disabled, and if yes, enable it.
If no, there are some problems in the code that you are using, but if you have replaced all files as you write, is most probably the first option.

Comment: I checked  phpinfo() and there is no issue in it.. There are many more websites hosted on same server.. They are working fine..

Comment: Have you tried to do a clean install and then replace all files?

Comment: You mean to install fresh wp and upload my theme and plugins file?

Comment: Yes, exatly. The idea is do a full backup (files+db), then a fresh install and finally replace all files. When you have found the problem, you can isolate it on your old system, and fix it without lose anything. Or you can reconfigure it completely, depending on your preferences.

Comment: Yes, i tried this.. Also, i tried to setup the same site on other server and its working fine there..

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem with a cpanel multiphp instance. Tried just about everything but while cpanel/whm was saying all was fine, the site would crash when 7.x was activated.

In the end, it was the .htaccess file. We renamed and let Cpanel regenerate and all is good.

Hope this helps someone out there as it took some time to resolve here.

Answer (score 0):

i had same kind of issue for my web hosting client at magicworkshost ,  i have updated php version from 5.6 to 7.3 and issue resolved successfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```