# Wordpress - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo()

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

Can anyone help me out on this error. I am setup my existing website on my localdisk using xampp but i m getting this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   get_currentuserinfo() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\google-analytics-for-wordpress\frontend\abstract-class-tracking.php:286
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\google-analytics-for-wordpress\frontend\abstract-class-tracking.php(51):
>   Yoast_GA_Tracking->do_tracking() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\google-analytics-for-wordpress\frontend\class-frontend.php(27):
>   Yoast_GA_Tracking->__construct() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\google-analytics-for-wordpress\googleanalytics.php(52):
>   Yoast_GA_Frontend->__construct() #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-settings.php(305)

Comment: Sounds like an outdated plugin.

Comment: ..also this question may be better suited for wordpress.stackexchange.com.  You might also try stack exchange's superuser  or server fault sites. As it's not directly related to writing code, it may be off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an outdated plugin, Update your plugin or you can try `wp_get_current_user()` function instead.

Its not a good idea to change the plugin code, but you can check that function whether it fixes things up or not, better option is to update your plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, May I know how to update the plugin manually. I am not coder. Or can I delete those files?

Comment: Log into the admin panel.
Go to plugins->installed plugins.
Click on the "update now" link of the plugin that you want to update.

You can follow [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-properly-update-wordpress-plugins-step-by-step/) article as well.

Comment: I couldnot login to wp admin as well. i getting this error! 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\css\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1197 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\css\wp-includes\wp-db.php(577): wpdb->db_connect() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\css\wp-content\plugins\w3-total-cache\lib\W3\Db.php(165): wpdb->__construct('root', '', 'ciphersoft', 'localhost')

Comment: Your current issue sounded like this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841823/wordpress-fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect