# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect on PHP for windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

I have xampp server installed in my windows 10 with this php version:

[image]

And this is the xampp version:

[image]

I am using wp-cli in order to import or export the database from local repository to a cloud repository.  When i use the wp-cli gives me this error.

[image]

I in wp-db.php chance mysql_connect to mysqli_connect but gives me the same error.
[image]

I check the environment variables.

[image]

I dont know what to do in order to resolve this problema, any advice?

Comment: enable extension=php_mysql.dll; from your INI file and give it a try  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825108/undefined-function-mysql-connect