# How to check the connectivity of GCE using PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a google cloud instance on Compute Engine. I want to check the connectivity using PHP code.

```
<?php
$dhost="my public IP";
$duser="username";
$dpassword="password";
$database="test";
$connection=mysqli_connect($dhost, $duser, $dpassword) or die("Could not Connect to SQL Server ");

?>
```

Getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqi_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbconnect.php:6
```

from my terminal i installed the following

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
 sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Still the problem exists..

Comment: `mysqi` or `mysqli`?

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825108/undefined-function-mysql-connect

Comment: @u_mulder thank you... really sorry...its typo..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a typo error and it was solved after changing

```
mysqi_connect
```

to

```
mysqli_connect
```

In the php file.